# C# - Ocultar o mostrar paneles dentro de un SplitPanel

Tags: c#, windows-forms

En un formulario tengo un SplitContainer: en el panel izquierdo tengo una serie de botones y en el derecho varios paneles ACOPLADOS al panel derecho del SplitContainer.

La idea es: al presionar los diferentes botones del panel izquierdo, que se muestren los diferentes paneles de la derecha (uno a la vez según el botón presionado, ya que los paneles están acoplados).

El problema que tengo es que al presionar por ejemplo el segundo boton, me muestra el panel de la derecha en blanco (como si se ocultaran todos los paneles contenidos en él) pero cuando presiono el primero para volver a la sección principal me muestra el panel correspondiente al segundo botón.

Código:

```
    //Segundo boton
    private void btnDatosGenerales_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OcultarOtrosPaneles(panDatosGen);
    }

    // Primer boton
    private void btnDatosPersonales_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OcultarOtrosPaneles(panDatosPer);
    }

    private void OcultarOtrosPaneles(Panel panelActivo)
    {
        foreach (Panel panel in this.splPrincipal.Panel2.Controls.OfType<Panel>())
        {
            panel.Visible = false;
        }
        panelActivo.Visible = true;
    }
```

Cosas que probé:

- Refrescar los paneles (con Refresh()).
- Pasar el parametro "panelActivo" como referencia.
- Usar el metódo BringToFront() o SendToBack() con los paneles según corresponda.

Alguna idea o sugerencia?

Comment: Intenta depurar tu codigo. Pon un breakpoint en el metodo ´OcultarOtrosPaneles´ y depura paso a paso a ver que le llega en ´panelActivo´

Comment: Hice lo que me recomendaste y encontré lo siguiente: al presionar el segundo botón me oculta directamente el panel2 del Split y al presionar el primer botón lo vuelve a mostrar. Es como si no estuviera funcionando lo de "por cada panel dentro de Split.Panel2"...

Comment: Es extraño. El código que te puse en ningun caso debe ocultar los paneles del splitter,si no los paneles que contiene el `Panel2`. si depuras el código paso a paso,deberias ver como ese foreach pasa dos veces ocultando tus dos paneles. Comprueba que no estes ocultando el `Panel2` en alguna otra parte de tu código

Comment: Muchas gracias Pikoh, fue un error de diseño mío. Cuando cree el segundo panel por error lo coloqué dentro del primero en lugar de colocarlo dentro del panel2 del Split. Lo que ocurría era que al ocultar el primer panel, como el segundo estaba contenido dentro de este también se ocultaba, graficamente lo que parecía era que se ocultaba todo el panel2 del Split, por eso mi confución.

Comment: Ya entiendo,esas cosas nos pueden pasar a cualquiera. Me alegro que te funcione :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo diría que tu problema puede estar aqui: `foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)`.

`this.Controls` se refiere probablemente al formulario, no al `SplitContainer`. Para recorrer todos los Paneles dentro del `SplitContainer`, yo haría algo asi:

```
foreach(Panel panel in this.splitContainer1.Panel2.Controls.OfType<Panel>())
{
    panel.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: Probé de esa forma, pero me oculta todos los controles. Estimo que se debe a que los dos paneles del Split son de tipo Panel, por lo cual los oculta también.

Comment: Este codigo debe ocultar todos los paneles que tengas dentro del ´Panel2´ de tu ´SplitContainer'. Despues de esto debes poner visible el panel correspondiente al boton pulsado. Los "paneles" del split no deberian ocultarse,edita si no tu pregunta con el nuevo codigo.

Comment: Perdón, error mío. Me faltó poner el .Panel2. Igualmente ahora tengo otro problema relacionado, edito la pregunta.